# How to speed up snabbdom rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, render

I have node.js project that renders html on back end. I'm using snabbdom for rendering. When there are a lot of requests to server, it slows down. I bet that it is because node is single thread and snabbdom rendering functions (like h1(span('text')) ) are not asynchronous. So, each render is blocking all other requests.
How to solve this issue? 
Is there any way to render snabbdom asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is DOM rendering, I guess it depends solely on CPU speed, so it's not async indeed. You're right, since Node is single-threaded, other requests are blocked while the CPU works. The solution would be to launch your app with [PM2 in cluster mode](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/) : `pm2 start app.js -i 0`. This way, if you have 8 cores, it'll launch 8 threads in parallel.

Comment: Thank you. Clusters may be the option. 
I'm more interested in timeouts. Bad there is no snabbdom-async lib. 
Next behavior will solve issue:

 h1(span('text')) should render in next way

1) render span; 
2) than, if there is another action in event queue do it;
3) render h1 using result of step (1). 
But I can't came up with code, that will work in this way.